# Rails weird behaviour with rails destroy migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Working on rails, i have noticed following behaviour with rails migration. I Don't know is it expected behaviour or not. Is anyone have any idea about it?

Step 1 - I have created a migration

`rails g migration CreateCustomer`

Result of this command -

```
  invoke  active_record
  create  db/migrate/20151012160803_create_customer.rb
```

Step 2 - Now i want to Undo code generated with above command.

```
rails d migration CreateCustomer
```

Result of this command -

```
  invoke  active_record
  remove  db/migrate/20151012160803_create_customer.rb
```

Step 3 - if i run the step 2 command `rails d migration CreateCustomer` again, i get differant results on different rails versions

Result on Rails 3.2.17 is -

```
  invoke  active_record
  remove  migration.rb
```

Result on Rails 4.0.0 is -

```
  invoke  active_record
  remove  create_table_migration.rb
```

My question is why rails removing `migration.rb` or `create_table_migration.rb` file? is rails really removing this files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't really remove this file if you will run:

`rails d migration SomeUnRealMigration`

you will get the same error, those 2 file names you see are core files of Rails create_table_migration.rb:

```
    class <%= migration_class_name %> < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :<%= table_name %> do |t|
        t.string :email,                null: false
        t.string :password_digest,      null: false
        t.string :password_reset_token, null: false, limit: 60
        <% attributes.each do |attribute| -%>
          <% if attribute.password_digest? -%>
            t.string :password_digest<%= attribute.inject_options %>
          <% else -%>
            t.<%= attribute.type %> :<%= attribute.name %><%= attribute.inject_options %>
          <% end -%>
       <% end -%>
       <% if options[:timestamps] %>
         t.timestamps
       <% end -%>
     end
    <% attributes_with_index.each do |attribute| -%>
      add_index :<%= table_name %>, :<%= attribute.index_name %><%= attribute.inject_index_options %>
    <% end -%>
    end
  end
```

this will not effect any file in your application.